# CSS Sprites not showing properly in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, sprite

I'm using a css sprite based navigation for wordpress, the page can be seen here:  http://asvpart.com/new/

There is an issue in IE 7 though, the images are showing greater dimensions that what are defined, both horizontally and vertically.  Is this a background position issue in IE 7?

Answer (score 0):

In `ie7.css`, you need to from `#menu ul li a` remove this:

```
padding:1.5em 2em 1em
```

That is the cause of the increased size of the `li`. Adding `padding` increases the size of an element.